# guardar el contenido de un TEXTAREA en un campo Tipo MEDIUMTEXT en mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

En html tengo el siguiente campo de un formulario,

```
<textarea id="qte_presentation" name="qte_presentation" form="quoteForm"></textarea>
```

lo recibo en php asi,

```
$qte_presentation = $_POST['qte_presentation'];
```

y lo grabo...

```
    $stmt->bindParam('qte_presentation', $qte_presentation, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

pero al campo de la base de datos mysql llega un string vacio, cual es la forma correcta de grabar este tipo de dato?

Muestro mas del codigo

```
try {

    $conn->beginTransaction();

    //prepre insert
    $insert = "INSERT INTO ".$database_table_prefix."quote_master(qte_prefix, qte_number, qte_dateTime, qte_dateDue, qte_empId, qte_payment, qte_cntId, qte_company, qte_contact, qte_address, 
    qte_phone, qte_email, qte_subject, qte_comment, qte_branch, qte_terminal, qte_userId, qte_presentation, qte_terms) 
    VALUES(:qte_prefix, :qte_number, :qte_dateTime, :qte_dateDue, :qte_empId, :qte_payment, :qte_cntId, :qte_company, :qte_contact, :qte_address, :qte_phone, :qte_email, :qte_subject, 
    :qte_comment, :qte_branch, :qte_terminal, :qte_userId, :qte_presentation, :qte_terms)"; 

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($insert);

    $stmt->bindParam('qte_prefix', $_POST['qte_prefix'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam('qte_number', $nextNum, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam('qte_dateTime', $qte_dateTime, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam('qte_dateDue', $_POST['qte_dateDue'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam('qte_empId', $_POST['qte_empId'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam('qte_payment', $_POST['qte_payment'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam('qte_cntId', $qte_cntId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam('qte_company', $_POST['qte_company'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam('qte_contact', $_POST['qte_contact'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam('qte_address', $_POST['qte_address'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam('qte_phone', $_POST['qte_phone'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam('qte_email', $_POST['qte_email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam('qte_subject', $_POST['qte_subject'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam('qte_comment', $_POST['qte_comment'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam('qte_branch', $qte_branch, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam('qte_terminal', $qte_terminal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam('qte_userId', $_POST['qte_userId'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam('qte_presentation', $qte_presentation, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam('qte_terms', $qte_terms, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Chequeaste que `$_POST['qte_presentation']` esté trayendo el valor del textarea?

Comment: si, hasta ahi llega bien

Comment: Mostrá el resto del código entonces, junto con el detalle de la DB.

Comment: Esa es toda la parte donde graba, pero no me da ningun error, pasa normar pero cuando veo el registro por el workbech esta vacio

Comment: Los demás campos si se guardan? Si hacés un `$stmt->bindParam('qte_presentation', 'texto de prueba', PDO::PARAM_STR);` se guarda? Como para ver de donde viene el problema. En el último código que pegaste no se ve donde creas `$qte_presentation`, eso está afuera? Podrías pegarlo completo por las dudas?

Comment: Puedes verificar que el tamaño del tipo de dato de tu tabla no supera el tamaño ingresado en el textarea